# multiple submit buttons only first initializes javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm echoing the Submit Button as seen below in each row of a Table. When clicked the Submit Button the Javascript initializes and alert()'s the response. The issue is only the first Button works as intended and subsequent buttons redirect to foobar.php.

Submit Button:

```
<form name="savefilenote" id="savefilenote" method="post" action="forbidden-savefilenote.php?notetype=2">Note: <input id="filenote" name="filenote" type="text" value="'.$filenote.'"> <input id="filename" name="filename" type="hidden" value="'.$filename.'"> <input type="submit" value="Save"></form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.savefilenote').on('submit', function(e){

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);

      if(data === "0") {
alert("foo");
      }

      if(data === "1") {
alert("bar");
      }    
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could it be because your input HTML is messed up? Maybe doublecheck your html bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class instead of an id.

`$("#savefilenote")` can find only one instance of a button since and ID works for a specific element. If you change it to `$(".savefilenote")` and apply the same class to all buttons it should work.

Comment: If I change     $('#savefilenote').on('submit', function(e){ to     $('.savefilenote').on('submit', function(e){ none of the Submit buttons execute the javascript. With # the first one does.

Comment: You have to change the html of the form to `class="savefilenote"` instead of `id="savefilenote"`.

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be specific to a single element. Using the same `id` to identify multiple tags, you'll end up only affecting the first element in the body. If you want to associate a behavior to a group of elements, you'll need to use a `class`.